# Why does Double.ToString("F1") behave differently in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, floating-point, .net-core-3.1

I've updated a project from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.1, and some of my unit tests are now failing in a surprising way.

For example, one of our tests is checking the formatting of a number (which should be rounded to 1 decimal place). The test has an input value of 1.65 and is expecting the result to be "1.7".

I've pared back the unit test to just the following, and it fails (the actual result is "1.6"):

```
Assert.Equal("1.7", 1.65.ToString("F1"));
```

I'm aware that floating-point handling was [changed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/) in .NET Core 3. However, from the description of those changes it looks like the differences should only affect the 15th decimal place.

I can only think that perhaps 1.65 is one of those numbers that's hard to represent in floating-point, and that it's actually being represented as 1.649999999999999 in the new world, which would indeed lead to it being rounded down?

Note: when I use the C# interactive console and enter `1.65.ToString("F1")` it comes out as "1.7"!

Comment: FWIW this is consistent with what `Math.Round(1.65d, 1)` would give you on both platforms -- that is, .NET's default round-to-even logic. I don't know if that was the intent, though.

Comment: _"I can only think that perhaps 1.65 is ... actually being represented as 1.649999999999999"_ -- that's easy enough to check. Did you bother to do so? If not, why not? If so, what did you find? It's not clear to me what you are asking here; you already know that there are some subtle changes to floating point in .NET Core 3, and you're aware that those changes could occasionally result in different floating point results, and that this could be one of those examples. What else are you expecting anyone to answer?

Comment: Re: my comment above: it was probably not the intent since for `1.65m` (decimal) `ToString("F1")` is `1.7` and `Math.Round` is `1.6`, again on both platforms. So giving the same result for `double` should be a coincidence... then again, rounding and string representations of floating-point values are supposed to be subject to IEEE rules while for `decimal` they can technically do whatever they please, so yeah.

Comment: `1.65` is not exactly  representable as a binary Double.  Instead the nearest is used whose exact value is 1.6499999999999999111...(29 more digits)...375.  Rounding to the nearest tenth would be 1.6

Comment: The *exact* value of `1.65` is 3715469692580659/2^51 = 1.65 - 1/11258999068426240.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Github issue describing your exact issue which can be found here:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1640

That issue is marked as closed due to the root cause issue being a problem with Math.Round:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1643

So yes, this is unexpected behavior that is a bug in .NET. The bug has a milestone of Future which means it is not expected to be fixed in an upcoming release.

Comment: It's not a bug. As chux said, the correct result would be 1.6 instead of 1.7 like in older .NET versions